# What does "parce" mean?

Tags: significado, coloquialismos, palabras-raras, colombia

I'm not from Colombia but I have some Colombian colleagues. I wonder, **what does "parce" means?** They use it quite like a word that can be substituted by "compadre", or in English, "dude", "man", "friend". But, what does it exactly mean?

Sorry about my ignorance if this word is not *only* used in Colombia.

Comment: No es necesario que hagas la pregunta en inglés. De hecho, creo que si la traduces obtendrás mejores respuestas.

Comment: Tranquilo :) En [French.SE](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/3123) y [German.SE](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6154) también se pueden hacer preguntas en sus respectivos idiomas. Puedes leer en nuestro [FAQ] al respecto.

Answer (score 5):

Según el [Diccionario de americanismos](http://asale.org/obras-y-proyectos/diccionarios/diccionario-de-americanismos), [«parce»](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=parce) es apócope de «parcero» en Colombia y Ecuador, y [«parcero, -a»](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=parcero) es una forma de tratamiento usada entre jóvenes (amigo íntimo, compañero inseparable).

Answer (score 1):

[Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=parce) to the rescue!

> Parce is a colombian slang for nigga or friends..bro..etc. this is a
>   only slang by YOUNG COLOMBIANS!! "quivo parce como a estado...todo
>   bien??"

Then you need to check its [etymology](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/aparcero#Espa.C3.B1ol).

Comment: yes, but one should be able to explain the word. As I mention in the question, I can infer the meaning, but ...I guess I need more information.

Comment: -1 For lack of explanation _adding external resources without explain or add context is not a appropiate answer IMHO_.

Answer (score 1):

En Colombia, se usa la palabra *parce* en lugar de *amigo* pero que de igual manera, tiene sus mismas connotaciones; un equivalente válido en inglés puede ser la palabra ["buddy"](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/parce).

A su vez, la palabra *parce* es la abreviación de [parcero](http://es.wiktionary.org/wiki/parcero#Espa.C3.B1ol).

> Amigo o compañero con quien se tiene mucha confianza.

As complement, the word nigga would be interpreted as reference to black people, that said, the word buddy is more adequate for avoid reference to color skin.